# Htaccess how to rewrite url - replace string

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to replace string '---' with '-' in url. Nothing works.

Example:
http://sportmix.pl/meindl/buty/klasyczne/buty-meindl-island-mfs-active---2816-493

Change into:
http://sportmix.pl/meindl/buty/klasyczne/buty-meindl-island-mfs-active-2816-493

Comment: What have you *tried*? What results did you expect? What happened instead? Any errors/warnings? ("Nothing works" is rather...nonspecific)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(.*?)--(.*)$ /$1-$2
```